# Due to Nullish Coalescing and Optional Chaining operators, on VS Code's terminal appear warnings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

When I implement any of the aforementioned operators in code, there are appear warnings. But code runs without any problem though. My question is, what would be able to cause such a weirdness?
PS: VScode version: 1.53.2

[image: here is screenshot]

Comment: Just curious, what is your typescript version?  `tsc -v`

Comment: version 1.4.1.0

Comment: That is the result of running the above command? I am at v4.1.3.